# Getting favicon to work in Chrome with base64 data

Tags: google-chrome, base64, favicon

I have searched the half of the day for this. It seems that its really easy for people to make it working.. But I have some problems getting Chrome to understand it. Its works in FF.

I have the icon in png format located in root.

Any ideas?

I'm using this code;

```
<link id=​"favicon" rel=​"shortcut icon" type=​"image/​png" href=​"data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Comment: Something to do with data is a url format on its own? How should I rewrite the line of code above if using data as a url?
`data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`

Comment: Its working now! I think my browser had some cache/cookie problem..