# How to I remove this 'evil cat' favicon from my application without supplying a favicon?

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I'm supplying the following favicon link in my application:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
```

In Chrome I get this 'evil cat' image as my favicon.

[image]

My question is: **How to I remove this 'evil cat' favicon from my application  without supplying a favicon?**

Comment: Related: [do you have to include `<link rel="icon">`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon)

Comment: The comment on [this duplicate but unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094053/getting-favicon-to-work-in-chrome-with-base64-data), suggests that your browser may have a cached favicon.